# How to check key state without reading input in shell script

Tags: bash

Instead of reading user input, I want my shell script to poll key state, that is, "Is key X currently held down", similar to how a key logger would work.

I want to capture input sent to another application.
It's my own input on my own machine, so rights and access shouldn't be an issue.

`sudo showkey` appears to dump roughly the information I need, but it runs continuously, and I don't know if I can poll that in a script.

Trying something like `showkey | head -n1` doesn't exit.

An attempt at pseudo code of what I want is:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
  key_pressed=$(showkey | head -n1)
  if [[ $key_pressed == "keycode  3 press" ]]; then
    echo "Key is down"
  else
    echo "Key is up"
  fi
  sleep .1
done;
```

Here's an attempts at reading anything from showkey into a script, but this just waits at read as if there's no output from showkey.

```
$ sudo bash -xc "showkey | head -n1 | while read -r a; do printf '%s\n' $a; done"
+ showkey
+ head -n1
+ read -r a
test
^C
```

Typing the same `test` phrase without piping showkeys output works better:

```
$ sudo bash -xc "showkey"
+ showkey
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
testkeycode  20 press
keycode  18 press
keycode  31 press
keycode  20 release
keycode  20 press
keycode  18 release
keycode  31 release
keycode  20 release

keycode  28 press
keycode  28 release
^Ccaught signal 2, cleaning up...
```

Comment: `showkey` isn't part of bash itself, so there are surely some tags missing. (That `showkey | head -n 1` doesn't exit is surprising, by the way; if the `showkey` tool doesn't quit when `head` closes the read side of the FIFO it's writing to, that's rather clearly a bug; I'd be less surprised if it just couldn't read keycodes because of lack of permissions without `sudo`, though still a _bit_ surprised if it doesn't exit immediately in the inadequate-permissions case).

Comment: ...that said, you might want to start by switching to a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like the question to be tagged with. showkey was just an example of what I've found myself that looks useful, I have no idea if it's appropriate for what I'm trying to do.
In response to the `while read` loop, I added some more to the question about attempting to use showkey.

Comment: Re tagging, `util-linux` if that's the package that `showkey` is from. That said, think about `while read -r evtclass keynum evttype _; do echo "running logic for event type $evtclass, key $keynum, type $evttype"; done < <(showkey)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy on ubuntu `showkey` is in `kbd` package - http://www.kbd-project.org/; it doesn't do anything clever when writing output so needs something like `... < <(unbuffer showkey)`

Comment: If it's writing direct to the TTY instead of to stdout, I'd call that excessive cleverness, rather than a lack thereof.

Comment: Are there alternative ways to acquire this information, so I can skip showkey?
While unbuffer does help in getting output, I still can't pipe this into head without the program stopping there, for reasons beyond me.